# Parsing JSON data in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone/iOS JSON parsing tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial)

I have been reading many tutorials on how to parse JSON data in Objective C but still I am unable to figure it out. I want to parse data from the JSON file and show it up on screen.

For example,

I want to parse data from [here](http://isbn.net.in/9781449394707.json) and get all the values of different retailers in different variables, so that I can use them later.

How can I do it?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813077/iphone-ios-json-parsing-tutorial

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241908/parsing-json-data-in-ios-objective-c-and-displaying-in-tableview-getting-empt

Comment: Look for more examples, and if you're having trouble understanding them your understanding of Objective-C is probably insufficient.  JSON is not that complicated!

Comment: (Of course, the example you have in not JSON, which may be one reason why you're not understanding it.)

Comment: (Let me repeat that.)  **THE EXAMPLE YOU HAVE IS NOT VALID JSON SYNTAX!** (It sorta, kinda looks like a dump of an Objective-C NSDictionary, but that shouldn't be served up as a web page.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have your data in a NSData object you can use NSJSONSerialization class available in iOS 5 and up.

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

This is a class method that will convert your data into objects like NSArray, NSDictionary, NSNumber etc. depending on the contents of your data object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would download and parse the data from a web server. Note that all these methods are part of the same class and there are instance variables named `_downloadData` of type `NSMutableData*` and `_downloadConnection` of type `NSURLConnection*`. Also note this code assumes ARC is not being used. If it is, just remove the object releases and retains and make sure the instance variables are strong references.

```
-(void)startDownload {
    NSURL* jsonURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://isbn.net.in/9781449394707.json"];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];

    _downloadData = [[NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:512] retain];

    _downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [_downloadData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_downloadData appendData:data];
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

   [_downloadConnection release];
   _downloadConnection = nil;

   [_downloadData release];
   _downloadData = nil;
}


- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError* jsonError = nil;

    NSDictionary* jsonDict = nil; // your data will come out as a NSDictionry from the parser
    jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&jsonError];


    if ( nil != jsonError ) {
        // do something about the error

        return;
    }

    [_downloadConnection release];
    _downloadConnection = nil;

    [_downloadData release];
    _downloadData = nil;

    // now do whatever you want with your data in the 'jsonDict'
}
```